# How to cast String to Int using PHP with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, casting, integer

I am working with an api written in php, that is getting data from a postgres database. one of the fields of data is however getting returned by the query as lexicographic sorted. I thus want to try casting it as integer. If that is wrong, please suggest me alternative approaches. Here's the relevant code snippet

```
case( 'location_group' ):
    $filter_label_column = 'location_group_' . $pk_location_group_type . '_name';

    if( !is_missing_or_empty( $request['params'], 'filter_label' ) )
    {
          $filter_label_column = 'location_group_' . $pk_location_group_type . '_' . $request['params']['filter_label'];
    }

    $query->select( [ $filter . "_$pk_location_group_type", 'pk' ], [ $filter_label_column, 'label' ] )
          ->group( $filter . "_$pk_location_group_type", $filter_label_column )
          ->order( 'label', 'asc' );
    break;
```

Tried casting in multiple ways, and as a result no data gets returned for the label, tried following (also tried replacing SIGNED with INTEGER):

```
case 'location_group':
    $filter_label_column = 'location_group_' . $pk_location_group_type . '_name';

    if (!is_missing_or_empty($request['params'], 'filter_label')) {
        $filter_label_column = 'location_group_' . $pk_location_group_type . '_' . $request['params']['filter_label'];
    }

    $query->select([$filter . "_$pk_location_group_type", 'pk'], ["CAST($filter_label_column AS SIGNED)", 'label'])
          ->group($filter . "_$pk_location_group_type", "CAST($filter_label_column AS SIGNED)")
          ->order('label', 'asc');
    break;
```

Comment: Wouldn't it make sense to use one of [the Numeric Date Types of PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html) for "label" in your database?

Comment: @KIKOSoftware I am not even sure if its not already stored as a string in the database. I am guessing it is not based on the displayed behavior. I unfortunately can't access the database right now for some reason. What do you recommend doing

Comment: Try this way `$query->select([$filter . "_$pk_location_group_type", 'pk'], [new \yii\db\Expression("CAST($filter_label_column AS SIGNED)"), 'label'])
        ->group($filter . "_$pk_location_group_type", new \yii\db\Expression("CAST($filter_label_column AS SIGNED)"))
        ->order('label', 'asc');`

Comment: Please do not comment "try this" answers.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you wish to cast a column in your PostgreSQL query to an integer in order to receive the data in a numeric format, but the example code makes use of PHP's SQL construction tools rather than actually performing the query. The correct way to cast a column in PostgreSQL to an integer is as follows:

```
case 'location_group':
    $filter_label_column = 'location_group_' . $pk_location_group_type . '_name';

    if (!is_missing_or_empty($request['params'], 'filter_label')) {
        $filter_label_column = 'location_group_' . $pk_location_group_type . '_' . $request['params']['filter_label'];
    }

    $query->select([
        $filter . "_$pk_location_group_type",
        'pk'
    ], [
        "CAST($filter_label_column AS INTEGER)",
        'label'
    ])->group($filter . "_$pk_location_group_type", "CAST($filter_label_column AS INTEGER)")
    ->order('label', 'asc');
    break;
```

You've used the `CAST` function to cast the `$filter_label_column` to an integer in this code, which is correct. Use `AS INTEGER` for the casting rather than `AS SIGNED`, though.

Verify that the information in the `$filter_label_column` is actually a string that can be cast to an integer if the results of this function don't match what was anticipated. You may need to handle non-integer numbers differently if they are present in the column, for as by filtering them out or setting a default value in the case of non-integer values.